# Undefined variable or method when adding answers to questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add answers to questions. Each questions has_one answer. I'm showing them on the comment page through partials except I keep getting this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `answer'
```

Here is part of my answers_controller.rb

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def index
  @question = Question.find params[:question_id]
  @question.answers
end


def show
end


def new
  @question = Question.find params[:question_id]
end


 def edit
 end


 def create
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  @answer = @question.answers.create(answer_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @answer.save
     format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @answer }
   else
     format.html { render action: 'new' }
     format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my _question.html.erb partial where the answer partial is called:

```
 <%=div_for(question) do %>
  <div class="questioncontainer">
  <p> 
<%= question.body %>

   <%= render :partial => @question.answers %>    

   <% if current_user == @comment.user %>
   <div class="answercontainer">
    <%= link_to 'Answer', new_question_answer_path(question)%>
 </div>


</div>
</p>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Last, here is my _answer.html.erb partial:

```
<%=div_for(answer) do %>
   <div class="questioncontainer">
   <p> 
<%= answer.body %>
  </p>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `answer` as local, via `locals: {answer: @answer}`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<%= render question.answers %>
```

instead of

```
<%= render :partial => @question.answers %>
```

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: Does it work if you add `, as: :answer` to the render options? I'm assuming the error message is coming from the  _answer.html.erb partial, right?

Comment: Yeah, the error comes from _answer.html.erb. I am able to render it with <%= render "answers/answer" %> but then the partial gives me the same error.

Comment: Try putting a `<% debugger %>` at the top of the _answer.html.erb partial. Then evaluate `local_assigns`. You can then see what local variables are defined. We're expecting `answer` to be defined but look and see what is, instead.

Comment: My first time using local_assigns so not sure what to make of it. When i have "<% if local_assigns.has_key? :answer %>  <% answer.body %><% end %>" it gives me the same error but with something like "<% if local_assigns.has_key? :answer %> hello <% end %> it works and shows hello.